# How to place a input (class="button") were I want

Tags: html, css, button, input

I can´t figure out how to place my input (class="button") were I want

html:

```
<div id="popup" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
<div id="content"> 
<select required name="list" id="list">
  <option value="0" selected disabled>SELECT</option>
  <option value="option1.html">option 1</option>
  <option value="option2.html">option 2</option>
</select>
</div>
<input class="button-go" type="button" value="GO"onclick="gotonewpage()"/>
```

css:

```
    .button-go {
position:relative;
top: 1%;
left: 42%;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 1.2vw; 
background-color: #0D7BFF;
color:#FDFDFD;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1 black; }
```

javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function gotonewpage()
{
    var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
    if(url != 'none') {
        window.location = url;
    }
}
```

The button is used to submit a value from a drop down box. I can only move the button horizontal, but I can´t put it alongside my dropdown menu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your code with the dropdown menu.

Comment: If you could make a JsFiddle so we can clearly see the problem that be awesome.

Comment: Just put the `button` inside the div with the `select`...they will automatically align alongside each other. - http://jsfiddle.net/17vz8dra/

Comment: That worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the the `display` value. I also recommend you to avoid `<input type ="button">` in HTML without a form. It's better to code it with `<button id="button" class="button-go">Send</button>`.

If it doesn't work, you can also change `margin-left`or`margin-top` to move your button where you want.

Comment: I can move it left and right, but not up and down. I have tried with both margin-top and padding-top as well as negative values. But it dosen't work

Comment: To display objects between them you must add inline-block display. If you are not able to move up and down maybe is because the height of one div avoid that move. Check also all your code with a firebug or similar in order to find some troubles like that.